# MAC cat-proof and kid-proof the keyboard and trackpad

Tags: macos

In MAC OS Catalina, is there a setting or app which can lock both keyboard and trackpad so that only typing some specific combination of keyboard keys will unlock them back.

Comment: Can’t you just sleep the computer? Then you can require your password to wake.

Comment: I want to play videos but my kid keeps typing on the computer

Comment: Just lock the screen. That should allow the music to continue.  https://osxdaily.com/2018/02/07/use-lock-screen-mac-os/

Comment: @EricShain: Thanks, atleast now I know how to play music. But my question was mainly so that I can watch videos

Comment: Maybe you could edit the question to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

[KeyboardCleanTool](https://folivora.ai/keyboardcleantool) will lock the entire keyboard & touchbar, but not the mouse/trackpad. It's a click to start, another to stop.